# How to sum data that lies between inconsistent time ranges?

Tags: postgresql, join, range, window

If I have data as such where the times and log events are in inconsistent intervals:

```
t1   data1
t2   data2
t3 log1
t4   data3
t5 log2
t6   data4
t7   data5
t8   data6
t9   data7
t10 log3
```

How can I get sums of the data between the log events?
ex:

```
t3 log1 sum(data 1-2)
t5 log2 sum(data 3)
t10 log3 sum(data 4-7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned time in the title, I'm guessing the `t` values are supposed to represent timestamps. I used a modified version of your data:

```sql
 key |       timestamp        | name  | value
-----+------------------------+-------+-------
 t1  | 2021-01-01 00:00:01-00 | data1 |     1
 t2  | 2021-01-01 00:00:02-00 | data2 |     2
 t3  | 2021-01-01 00:00:03-00 | log1  |
 t4  | 2021-01-01 00:00:04-00 | data3 |     3
 t5  | 2021-01-01 00:00:05-00 | log2  |
 t6  | 2021-01-01 00:00:06-00 | data4 |     4
 t7  | 2021-01-01 00:00:07-00 | data5 |     5
 t8  | 2021-01-01 00:00:08-00 | data6 |     6
 t9  | 2021-01-01 00:00:09-00 | data7 |     7
 t10 | 2021-01-01 00:00:10-00 | log3  |
```

Step 1 would be to figure out what the ranges are. We can query just the "log" rows, and use the `LAG` window function to make them into timeranges:

```sql
SELECT 
  key, 
  name, 
  tstzrange(LAG(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp), timestamp) as timerange 
FROM your_table 
WHERE name LIKE 'log%';

 key | name |                      timerange
-----+------+-----------------------------------------------------
 t3  | log1 | (,"2021-01-01 00:00:03-00")
 t5  | log2 | ["2021-01-01 00:00:03-00","2021-01-01 00:00:05-00")
 t10 | log3 | ["2021-01-01 00:00:05-00","2021-01-01 00:00:10-00")
```

Step 2, then, is to group the data rows using these timeranges. Note the `@>` operator, which checks if a timestamp is within a timerange:

```sql
WITH ranges AS (
  SELECT 
    key, 
    name, 
    tstzrange(LAG(timestamp) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp), timestamp) as timerange 
  FROM your_table 
  WHERE name LIKE 'log%'
)
SELECT 
  ranges.key, 
  ranges.name,
  SUM(value) 
FROM your_table
JOIN ranges ON (ranges.timerange @> your_table.timestamp)
WHERE your_table.name LIKE 'data%'
GROUP BY ranges.key, ranges.name;

 key | name | sum
-----+------+-----
 t3  | log1 |   3
 t5  | log2 |   3
 t10 | log3 |  22
```

Comment: Great, thank you.  I will try this out.  I was attempting something similar but it wouldn't allow window functions in the grouping or join sections...clearly the @> and range functions were my missing pieces.